# How to get current updated value in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm developing a node server that when ever data added to the firebase database the node js will pass that data to a webhook so that the webhook will do some crud operations based on that data.

I wrote this in my  script

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/events");

ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot);
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

when ever i enter the data into the firebase I'm getting the whole node. But i need only the property that I've changed.
Here is my firebase db structure

```
{
  "parent": {
       "child" : {
                   "name" :"test",
                   "address":{
                         "city":"NY",
                         "area":"Time Square"
                       }
                 }
     }
}
if I change the value of area Time Square to Brooklyn, I want to get only the node 

"address":{
...
}
```

but I'm getting whole object like this

```
"parent" : {
 ....
}
```

is there any way to get only the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK fires the `child_changed` event for each child that has changed. The `snapshot` for the event contains the entire child node. There is no information included in there about what specific properties of the child have changed.